# What are some possible reasons for a large condition number?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, regression

For this question, please assume that I am talking about the condition number with respect to the spectral norm. That is, $\kappa_2(A) = \|A\|_2\|A^{-1}\|_2 = \frac{\sigma_{max}(A)}{\sigma_{min}(A)}$.

Many textbooks about linear regression claim that a large condition number implies the presence of multicollinearity. However, consider the following example:

Assume U is an orthonormal matrix, and define $\Sigma$ as follows:
\begin{equation*}
\Sigma = \pmatrix{10^{6}&0\\0&1}
\end{equation*}

Now let A = U$\Sigma$I. We have that $\sigma_{max}(A) = 10^6$ and $\sigma_{min}(A) = 1$, so $\kappa(A) = 10^6$. However, the columns of $A$ are not correlated (in fact, they're orthogonal). Hence, it seems that multicollinearity is not a necessary condition for a large condition number. In this case, we have orthogonal predictors on vastly different scales. What are some other reasons for a large condition number?

(Side question: can anyone prove that a higher correlation among the columns of $A$ implies a larger condition number?).

Comment: consider $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & \epsilon \end{bmatrix}$. Then, $\sigma_\max \approx 1$ and $\sigma_\min \approx \epsilon$. You got the idea?

Comment: @user251257 you gave me another example of a matrix that does not have correlated columns, but does have a high condition number. Thanks! However, I am looking for more general remarks concerning high condition numbers like the two I mentioned in my question (e.g. multicollinearity, poor scaling).

Comment: just transposed it if you want nearly dependent columns instead of rows. the condition stays the same.

Comment: Having a large condition number indeed means that the rows/columns are "almost" linearly dependent. Imagine for simplicity that $\|A\|_2=1$ so that the ill-conditioning of $A$ comes from a small minimal singular value of $A$. Then $\|Ax\|_2=\sigma_\min(A)\ll 1$ for some $x$ such that $\|x\|_2=1$. That is, you can combine the columns of $A$ with a "reasonably normalized" coefficient vector $x$ giving you an "almost zero" vector $Ax$.